# How to "collapse" rows that meet logic criteria in GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]: 
            A                               ID3            DATETIME
0  BRT-481028  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 13:43:27
1  BRT-481054  4a57ed0b02fa357bf3c51cc9460e8d96 2014-10-08 14:26:19
2  BRT-481076  1a682034f8cbc542f36e46215635da9a 2014-10-08 14:29:01
3  BRT-481023  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:39:34
4  BRT-481023  f88g8d7sds799asde83b2523944p9r78 2014-10-08 18:40:18
5  BRT-481033  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:44:30
6  BRT-481032  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:46:00
7  BRT-481037  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:52:15
8  BRT-481046  db959faf023e5df33032db4808882f0c 2014-10-08 18:59:59
9  BRT-481053  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 19:17:48
10 BRT-481065  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 19:21:38
```

Each row represents an ***event*** triggered by a *user* - identified for the sake of this example by value in *`df['ID3']`*. There are lots more attributes attached to each event, but I've clipped everything else out.

For what I'm trying to build, I only need to keep one event per user and per 5 minute *rolling* period. All other events, in the same time period and by the same user, are just noise that interfere with other logic that is executed further down and should therefore be discarded. So, I need to keep a maximum of one record per user and 5 minute ***rolling period***. More specifically I need to keep the latest record out of any number of records in the same time period.

The desired output would look like this:

```
            A                               ID3            DATETIME
0  BRT-481028  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 13:43:27
1  BRT-481054  4a57ed0b02fa357bf3c51cc9460e8d96 2014-10-08 14:26:19
2  BRT-481076  1a682034f8cbc542f36e46215635da9a 2014-10-08 14:29:01
4  BRT-481023  f88g8d7sds799asde83b2523944p9r78 2014-10-08 18:40:18
6  BRT-481032  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:46:00
7  BRT-481037  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:52:15
8  BRT-481046  db959faf023e5df33032db4808882f0c 2014-10-08 18:59:59
10 BRT-481065  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 19:21:38
```

Records on rows `[3,5,9]` above having been discarded as they met the criteria described above. Also, notice how between rows `3` and `6` the time gap was greater than 5 minutes, however, since record `5` was created in the meantime, the *rolling* window was such that these records were discarded.

Also notice that record on row `4` was left intact, as it was associated to a different user.

***EDIT***

Now I have come a bit further, I have used `diff()` and `groupby()` to see reach to this:

```
In [309]: df['diff'] = df.sort_values(by='DATETIME').groupby('ID3')['DATETIME'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())

In [310]: df
Out[310]: 
             A                               ID3            DATETIME  \
0   BRT-481028  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 13:43:27   
1   BRT-481054  4a57ed0b02fa357bf3c51cc9460e8d96 2014-10-08 14:26:19   
2   BRT-481076  1a682034f8cbc542f36e46215635da9a 2014-10-08 14:29:01   
3   BRT-481023  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:39:34   
4   BRT-481023  f88g8d7sds799asde83b2523944p9r78 2014-10-08 18:40:18   
5   BRT-481033  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:44:30   
6   BRT-481032  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:46:00   
7   BRT-481037  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 18:52:15   
8   BRT-481046  db959faf023e5df33032db4808882f0c 2014-10-08 18:59:59   
9   BRT-481053  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 19:17:48   
10  BRT-481065  b76cd912ffcb97e21de83b252391b2a0 2014-10-08 19:21:38   

                  diff  
0                  NaT  
1                  NaT  
2                  NaT  
3  1970-01-01 04:56:07  
4                  NaT  
5  1970-01-01 00:04:56  
6  1970-01-01 00:01:30  
7  1970-01-01 00:06:15  
8                  NaT  
9  1970-01-01 00:25:33  
10 1970-01-01 00:03:50
```

I cannot seem to be able to get number of seconds for the diff. I have tried with:

```
>> findTheDiff = lambda x: x.diff().astype(np.int64)
```

in the place of the `lambda` above, but that didn't do much of difference.

I would like for `'1970-01-01 00:01:30'` to become `'90'` !

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should start by solving the problem for a single user, with a function `func`. You can then apply the solution to the entire dataframe: `df.groupby('ID3').apply(func)`.

Comment: I find your approach strange. Consider rows `3, 5, 6`. You start the timer at row `3`. Row `5` comes less than 5 minutes later, so you discard `3` and keep `5`. Then comes row `6`. If I understand correctly, you say you discard `5` and keep `6` because `6` came less than 5 minutes after `5`. However, imagine a situation where you have one row every minute. If you apply the same rule you will keep discarding them, and end up with nothing except the last one. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, this is correct! In a scenario like this, I would like to only keep the last event record and discard all the ones leading up to it. There are many more attributes describing each record, and I will not go into depth, but think of it like Google trying to eliminate double-clicks on AdWords. They should only register one event. Their rules are likely a little different, but you get the picture, I'm just trying to eliminate noise in my dataset, there are lots of rows that carry very semantics if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `transform()` is not returning the correct dtype in this case, related to a known [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10972).

Working with `transform()` should indeed work here, however, given the erratic behaviour, a workaround would be to try this:

```
>> df.sort_values(by='DATETIME').groupby('ID3')['DATETIME'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
Out[168]:
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3     17767.0
4         NaN
5       296.0
6        90.0
7       375.0
8         NaN
9      1533.0
10      230.0
```

This also returns a like-indexed DF (as `transform` does) and does the job just fine.

Original answer, as well as more information regarding the fault with `transform()` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960086/groupby-how-to-extract-seconds-from-datetime-with-diff)

Answer (score 1):

The `diff` is returning `Timedelta` objects that have a `seconds` property.

#### Solution (maybe)

```
findTheDiff = lambda x: x.diff().seconds
```

Comment: You would indeed expect `diff()` to return a `TimeDelta`, however, it appears that there is some faulty behaviour, related to a known [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10972) and more specifically related to `transform` in this case.

Comment: Actual solution to this issue found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960086/groupby-how-to-extract-seconds-from-datetime-with-diff). Thanks for the time and effort!