# GroupBy - How to extract seconds from DateTime with diff()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
In [372]: df_2
Out[372]: 
        A         ID3            DATETIME
0   B-028  b76cd912ff 2014-10-08 13:43:27
1   B-054  4a57ed0b02 2014-10-08 14:26:19
2   B-076  1a682034f8 2014-10-08 14:29:01
3   B-023  b76cd912ff 2014-10-08 18:39:34
4   B-023  f88g8d7sds 2014-10-08 18:40:18
5   B-033  b76cd912ff 2014-10-08 18:44:30
6   B-032  b76cd912ff 2014-10-08 18:46:00
7   B-037  b76cd912ff 2014-10-08 18:52:15
8   B-046  db959faf02 2014-10-08 18:59:59
9   B-053  b76cd912ff 2014-10-08 19:17:48
10  B-065  b76cd912ff 2014-10-08 19:21:38
```

And I want to find the difference between different entries - grouped by `'ID3'`.

I am trying to use `transform()` on a `GroupBy` like this:

```
In [379]: df_2['diff'] = df_2.sort_values(by='DATETIME').groupby('ID3')['DATETIME'].transform(lambda x: x.diff()); df_2['diff']
Out[379]: 
0                    NaT
1                    NaT
2                    NaT
3    1970-01-01 04:56:07
4                    NaT
5    1970-01-01 00:04:56
6    1970-01-01 00:01:30
7    1970-01-01 00:06:15
8                    NaT
9    1970-01-01 00:25:33
10   1970-01-01 00:03:50
Name: diff, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I have also tried with `x.diff().astype(int)` for `lambda`, with the exact same result.

Datatype of both `'DATETIME'` and `'diff'` is: `datetime64[ns]`

What I am trying to achieve is have `diff` represented in seconds instead of some time in relation to Epoch time.

I have figured out that I can convert `df_2['diff']` to `TimeDelta` and then extract seconds in one chained call at this point, like this:

```
In [405]: df_2['diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_2['diff']).map(lambda x: x.total_seconds()); df_2['diff']
Out[407]: 
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3     17767.0
4         NaN
5       296.0
6        90.0
7       375.0
8         NaN
9      1533.0
10      230.0
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to achieve this (seconds as values for `df_2['diff']`) in one step in the `transform` instead of having to take a couple of steps in the process?

Finally, I have already tried making conversion to `TimeDelta` in `transform` without any success.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** `transform()` from `class NDFrameGroupBy(GroupBy)` doesn't seem to do downcasting and works as expected:

```
In [220]: (df_2[['ID3','DATETIME']]
   .....:      .sort_values(by='DATETIME')
   .....:      .groupby('ID3')
   .....:      .transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds())
   .....: )
Out[220]:
    DATETIME
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3    17767.0
4        NaN
5      296.0
6       90.0
7      375.0
8        NaN
9     1533.0
10     230.0
```

the `transform()` from `class SeriesGroupBy(GroupBy)` tries to do the following:

```
result = _possibly_downcast_to_dtype(result, dtype)
```

which could (i'm not sure) cause your problem

**OLD answer:**

try this:

```
In [168]: df_2.sort_values(by='DATETIME').groupby('ID3')['DATETIME'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
Out[168]:
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3     17767.0
4         NaN
5       296.0
6        90.0
7       375.0
8         NaN
9      1533.0
10      230.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks! Is there some issue with cahining inside transform or what is the reason this cannot be done inside `transform`?

Comment: @Thanos, please see "UPDATE"